# Passing in method reference to a struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct `other_struct` that has a bunch of methods that I need to call depending on certain situations (in this example there is only `foo()`. I'd like to have a field in `other_struct` called `fmap` that stores a HashMap of `other_struct` methods.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct fn_struct {
    pub func: Option<fn(&other_struct) -> ()>,
}

pub struct other_struct<'a> {
    fmap: HashMap<String, fn_struct>,
    some_str: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> other_struct<'a> {
    fn new(some_str: &str) -> other_struct {
        let mut new_struct = other_struct {
            fmap: HashMap::new(),
            some_str: some_str,
        };

        new_struct.fmap.insert(
            String::from("foo"),
            fn_struct {
                func: Some(other_struct::foo),
            },
        );

        new_struct
    }

    pub fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Do some stuff foo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test_str = "test";
    let mut new_o = other_struct::new(test_str);
    new_o.fmap.get("foo").unwrap().func.unwrap()(&new_o);
}
```

I'm struggling with dealing with the lifetimes, as I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:28
   |
22 |                 func: Some(other_struct::foo),
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r other_struct<'s>)`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r other_struct<'_>)`
```

I've been reading the high ranked trait bound documentation but it's unclear to me what's happening here. Does this mean the compiler wants me to specify the lifetime of the instance of `other_struct` somehow in relation to the lifetime of the pointer to the method?

Comment: Your `fn_struct` doesn't specify a lifetime for the reference on `other_struct` or the `other_struct` itself, so it's inferred to work for all possible lifetimes (`for<'r, 's> fn(&'r other_struct<'s>)`). However, when you do `other_struct::foo`, you're only getting the method for a fixed lifetime, which gives you `for<'r> fn(&'s other_struct<'_>)`

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9275cd0d2e800cc683f70b7a50bc12a5

Comment: your MCVE is not clear, your method `bar` is saying "do something with foo" but it's take a `&self` and so a `&Bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fn(&other_struct) -> ()` part of `fn_struct` is a function pointer that must be able to accept `other_struct`s of any lifetime `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r other_struct<'s>) -> ()`. However, `other_struct::foo` only accepts a specific lifetime for `other_struct<'_>`.

You can fix it by specifying that lifetime in some manner, here basically saying its always going to pass in itself:

```
pub struct fn_struct<'a> {
    pub func: Option<fn(&other_struct<'a>) -> ()>,
}

pub struct other_struct<'a> {
    fmap: HashMap<String, fn_struct<'a>>,
    some_str: &'a str,
}
```

Or by making `foo` more generic by unbinding it from `'a`.

```
pub fn foo(_self: &other_struct) {
    println!("Do some stuff foo");
}
```

The difference is subtle, but the original is `other_struct<'a>::foo<'b>(&'b other_struct<'a>) -> ()` and the fixed version is `other_struct<'a>::foo<'b, 'c>(&'b other_struct<'c>) -> ()`.